# Solr import does nothing

Tags: java, apache, solr

I started Solr and ran the following query:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&commit=true"
```

I then checked the output in the Solr log buffer:

> Jan 27, 2012 5:08:23 PM
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport INFO:
>   Starting Full Import Jan 27, 2012 5:08:23 PM
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute INFO: [] webapp=/solr
>   path=/dataimport params={command=full-import&commit=true} status=0
>   QTime=7  Jan 27, 2012 5:08:23 PM
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter readIndexerProperties
>   INFO: Read dataimport.properties Jan 27, 2012 5:08:23 PM
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 deleteAll INFO: []
>   REMOVING ALL DOCUMENTS FROM INDEX Jan 27, 2012 5:08:23 PM
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy onInit INFO:
>   SolrDeletionPolicy.onInit: commits:num=1
>     commit{dir=/private/var/www/html/internsolr/solr/example/solr/data/index,segFN=segments_2b,version=1320251100997,generation=83,filenames=[segments_2b]
>   Jan 27, 2012 5:08:23 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy
>   updateCommits INFO: newest commit = 1320251100997 Jan 27, 2012 5:08:23
>   PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call INFO:
>   Creating a connection for entity id with URL:
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:8983/internshipsearch

Also, the XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">7</int></lst><lst name="initArgs"><lst name="defaults"><str name="config">data-config.xml</str></lst></lst><str name="command">full-import</str><str name="status">idle</str><str name="importResponse"/><lst name="statusMessages"/><str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.</str>
</response>
```

Note the statusMessages node is empty. I am guessing this means that nothing imported because when I run my application to view the data, nothing loads....

Here is an example of a correct statusMessages block:
http://digitalpbk.com/apachesolr/apache-solr-mysql-sample-data-config

**UPDATE**
**Exception appearing after about 80 seconds**

```
Jan 27, 2012 5:18:23 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: Exception while processing: id document : SolrInputDocument[{}]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select respondentid,                           first_name,                           last_name,                           cmc_email_address,                           graduation_year,                           first_major,                           additional_major,                           sequence,                           other_major,                           organization_name,                           organization_website,                           organization_desc,                           industry,                           job_title,                           department,                           city,                           state,                           country,                           region,                           internship_paid,                           hourly_salary,                           year_undertaken,                           recommend_again,                           employer_supervisor,                           employer_phone,                           employer_email,                           not_recommended_desc,                           full_time_offer,                           full_time_accept,                           attend_summer_classes,                           summer_classes_institution,                           summer_classes_desc,                           summer_travel,                           summer_travel_city,                           summer_travel_state,                           summer_travel_country,                           summer_other_activity,                           summer_other_activity_desc,                           how_discovered,                           doe_start_month,                           doe_start_day,                           doe_end_month,                           doe_end_day             from interndata Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.EOFException

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1913)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:501)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.EOFException

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1913)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:501)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:569)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2741)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
    ... 11 more

Jan 27, 2012 5:18:23 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: Full Import failed:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: select respondentid,                           first_name,                           last_name,                           cmc_email_address,                           graduation_year,                           first_major,                           additional_major,                           sequence,                           other_major,                           organization_name,                           organization_website,                           organization_desc,                           industry,                           job_title,                           department,                           city,                           state,                           country,                           region,                           internship_paid,                           hourly_salary,                           year_undertaken,                           recommend_again,                           employer_supervisor,                           employer_phone,                           employer_email,                           not_recommended_desc,                           full_time_offer,                           full_time_accept,                           attend_summer_classes,                           summer_classes_institution,                           summer_classes_desc,                           summer_travel,                           summer_travel_city,                           summer_travel_state,                           summer_travel_country,                           summer_other_activity,                           summer_other_activity_desc,                           how_discovered,                           doe_start_month,                           doe_start_day,                           doe_end_month,                           doe_end_day             from interndata Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.EOFException

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1913)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:501)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.EOFException

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1913)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:501)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:569)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2741)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
    ... 11 more

Jan 27, 2012 5:18:23 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: start rollback
Jan 27, 2012 5:18:23 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: end_rollback
```

Comment: Could you add DIH config? From exception there is something about query. Have you tried running it by your self.

Comment: As for status message, when you ask for full import first xml is not having info. Wait 1s and try http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=status (as many times as you want)

Comment: @Fuxi, I have no idea what DIH config is. Also, I ran the query in MySQL and it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the status idea although, this gives me the same information I had before. And the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that my AjaxSolr.Manager was setup incorrectly. By default, Solr listens on port 8983 but I had it listening on 1024. Here is the correct snippet:

```
Manager = new AjaxSolr.Manager({solrUrl: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/'});
```